# How do snaps work exactly and why are they mounted?

Tags: package-management, deb, snap, rpm

Recently I started learning more about snap packages and what intrigued me was that snap packages are mounted together with their own file system and dependencies (correct me if I'm wrong). Now, with all the great things that snaps bring to the table, what I'd like to know is:

Are snap packages always going to be mounted? This seems kind of awkward, since they appear in places like `lsblk` and give the impression of not being well integrated into my system.

Also, could they ever replace `.deb` and `.rpm` packages completely, or are they a different type of animal and are only complementary to `.deb` and`.rpm` packages?

As a side-note, I noticed that some applications are so self-contained that they don't respect any of my desktop settings like the mouse cursor theme or icon and menu themes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Snap packages are `squashfs` file systems. The only way to access snaps is to mount them. So yes, they will *always* be mounted.

They are a different thing from what traditional package managers implement. I would say they are neither a replacement for `.deb` packages, nor are they complimentary.