# Ubuntu 18.04 system monitor shows 70 partitions?

Tags: system-installation, files, system, partitioning

I have one 500GB HDD. I did not formated it, but have selected "Erase disk and install Ubuntu 18.04" option.

Now, when I open System Monitor it shows 70 partitions. And 490,7 GB one is shown 16 times.

What is happening?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "70 partitions"? Where? I see loop devices. Loop devices are NOT partitions; those are snaps.

Comment: Hi Против Глобал! This are mainly **snap** devices. There consists a problem that more than 2 snaps are kept. See the following link: https://askubuntu.com/q/1047456/790920

Comment: Thanks. Well, how could I have known? I don't even know what those "loop devices" are. Never heard of such thing. And you all talk about them like they are something obvious. I have been using Ubuntu since 11.10, and I have never seen this. It had always only been partitions.

Comment: I did not find the solution on how to set it to show only partitions in system monitor. :/

Comment: Yup. that's the way it is nowadays.  Use `mount | grep /dev/sd` in a terminal instead.