# GNOME System Monitor is showing tons of file systems (18.04.3)

Tags: gnome

I installed Ubuntu on 2 PCs the past few days. On one it was Kubuntu 18.04.3 -> Install ubuntu-desktop and I get the monitor showing file systems nicely, like this:

[image]

The second computer, causing me this issue, was a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.3 yesterday and the monitor shows file systems with a crazy amount like this:

[image]

The only setting I see that might pertain to this is 'Show all file systems', which is unchecked:

[image]

Searching here and Googling haven't brought me anyone with the same issue.

Comment: Welcome to the "wonderful" world of snaps.

Comment: I see.. I never figured a core system package would be a snap. I installed the normal package from the repo, even though it is an older version.. and it works perfectly as expected.

Comment: @N0rbert It does, yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Install the gnome-system-monitor from the repos, and use that. For some reason Ubuntu ships with a Snap version, which does this insanity.

This has already been answered here: [Why are all snaps being mounted and listed as block devices or partitions for Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047456/why-are-all-snaps-being-mounted-and-listed-as-block-devices-or-partitions-for-ub)

Even though I saw this question before posting, it was not obvious without reading the whole thing what it was even talking about - didn't seem to be relevant when I skimmed the first few sentences from my search result.