# Where did this '52 MB Volume' come from?

Tags: nautilus

I've just gone into Nautilus on Ubuntu 20.04 and can see what appears to be a volume called '52 MB Volume' which has just appeared out of nowhere. Looking at the properties it contains 15,826 items totalling 148.9 MB, however it says it has a total capacity of 52.3 MB with 0 bytes free. Owner is root.

In disks, the mount point is `/media/'username'/disk.`

Other info from Disks - `52 MB Loop Device - /dev/loop10 (Read-Only) - Backing File /var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_467.snap (deleted) - Contents Unknown (squashfs 4.0)`

Anyone have ideas what's going on here?

Comment: What's the mount point? You can see more detail about it in the Disks application.

Comment: In disks, the mount point is /media/'username'/disk. Other info from Disks - 52 MB Loop Device -  /dev/loop10 (Read-Only) - Backing File /var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_467.snap (deleted) - Contents Unknown (squashfs 4.0)

Comment: It's a filesystem created by your friendly local snapd.  Opinions vary here whether that is a bug or a feature.  See https://askubuntu.com/q/1047456/243321

Comment: I see. Upon reboot that partition has disappeared now anyway.. I guess it was a temporary system thing..

Comment: The same just happened to me. Only the "Volume" is 130MB.