# Can't mount my external hard drive, PC is showing unknown error but it work properly with my TV

Tags: mount, hard-drive, mountpoint

fdisk -l

output

```
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop0: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop1: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop2: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop3: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop4: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop5: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop6: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop7: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop8: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop9: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop10: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop11: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop12: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop13: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop14: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop15: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop16: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop17: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop18: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop19: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: Permission denied
```

Comment: You haven't mention your OS & release, but if I use that command on my release I get the same results, as you need to elevate permissions with `sudo`, ie. `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: its Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I plugged it in my old win7 PC
used command chckdsk /f i:
i is the drive letter

https://youtu.be/Ix13LRGmzk8

but what is /dev/loop and all these things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are all snaps being mounted and listed as block devices or partitions for Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047456/why-are-all-snaps-being-mounted-and-listed-as-block-devices-or-partitions-for-ub)

Comment: Yes, now i can use my hard drive but what are these loop1,2,3,4....??