# Tens of file systems from `$ df -hT`: is it ok?

Tags: mount, filesystem, defrag

I was trying to follow this link to check if my system needs a defrag, and I found out this. Is it ok?

```
$ df -hT
File system    Type      Dim. Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  7.6G     0    7.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G  156M    1.4G  10% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p3 ext4      933G  582G    303G  66% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.7G  285M    7.4G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K    5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.7G     0    7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0     squashfs  768K  768K       0 100% /snap/amazon-webapp/3
/dev/loop1     squashfs  128K  128K       0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop2     squashfs   11M   11M       0 100% /snap/auto-cpufreq/124
/dev/loop4     squashfs  117M  117M       0 100% /snap/core/14946
/dev/loop6     squashfs  128K  128K       0 100% /snap/cpufreq/1
/dev/loop7     squashfs  117M  117M       0 100% /snap/core/14784
/dev/loop8     squashfs   56M   56M       0 100% /snap/cups/872
/dev/loop12    squashfs   56M   56M       0 100% /snap/cups/836
/dev/loop20    squashfs   97M   97M       0 100% /snap/discord/153
/dev/loop19    squashfs  6.5M  6.5M       0 100% /snap/curl/1679
/dev/loop17    squashfs   98M   98M       0 100% /snap/discord/151
/dev/loop21    squashfs  165M  165M       0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/194
/dev/loop22    squashfs  165M  165M       0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198
/dev/loop23    squashfs  219M  219M       0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/93
/dev/loop24    squashfs  219M  219M       0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/90
/dev/loop25    squashfs  350M  350M       0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/137
/dev/loop26    squashfs  350M  350M       0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/140
/dev/loop29    squashfs  2.7M  2.7M       0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/178
/dev/loop31    squashfs  1.5M  1.5M       0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/181
/dev/loop30    squashfs  256K  256K       0 100% /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13
/dev/loop32    squashfs   82M   82M       0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
/dev/loop33    squashfs   92M   92M       0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop36    squashfs  981M  981M       0 100% /snap/intellij-idea-community/430
/dev/loop35    squashfs  437M  437M       0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20/7
/dev/loop40    squashfs  438M  438M       0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-99-qt-5-15-7-core20/15
/dev/loop38    squashfs  425M  425M       0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20/8
/dev/loop39    squashfs  438M  438M       0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-98-qt-5-15-6-core20/9
/dev/loop44    squashfs   85M   85M       0 100% /snap/netflix-viewer/18
/dev/loop45    squashfs   70M   70M       0 100% /snap/overleaf/4
/dev/loop46    squashfs   65M   65M       0 100% /snap/prospect-mail/16
/dev/loop49    squashfs  112M  112M       0 100% /snap/shutter/27
/dev/loop50    squashfs  606M  606M       0 100% /snap/pycharm-community/329
/dev/loop52    squashfs  158M  158M       0 100% /snap/spotify/64
/dev/loop53    squashfs   82M   82M       0 100% /snap/prospect-mail/22
/dev/loop55    squashfs  207M  207M       0 100% /snap/ubuntu-app-platform/34
/dev/loop57    squashfs  296M  296M       0 100% /snap/vlc/2344
/dev/loop56    squashfs  321M  321M       0 100% /snap/vlc/3078
/dev/nvme0n1p1 vfat      786M   82M    705M  11% /boot/efi
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G  256K    1.6G   1% /run/user/1001
/dev/loop58    squashfs   64M   64M       0 100% /snap/core20/1879
/dev/loop16    squashfs  461M  461M       0 100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/102
/dev/loop59    squashfs  449M  449M       0 100% /snap/kf5-5-105-qt-5-15-9-core22/9
/dev/loop41    squashfs   56M   56M       0 100% /snap/core18/2745
/dev/loop60    squashfs   74M   74M       0 100% /snap/core22/634
/dev/loop14    squashfs  360M  360M       0 100% /snap/kdenlive/87
/dev/loop15    squashfs  606M  606M       0 100% /snap/pycharm-community/332
/dev/loop42    squashfs  981M  981M       0 100% /snap/intellij-idea-community/434
/dev/loop34    squashfs  151M  151M       0 100% /snap/chromium/2477
/dev/loop11    squashfs   64M   64M       0 100% /snap/whatsapp-for-linux/56
/dev/loop51    squashfs   64M   64M       0 100% /snap/core20/1891
/dev/loop61    squashfs  141M  141M       0 100% /snap/skype/277
/dev/loop48    squashfs  158M  158M       0 100% /snap/spotify/67
/dev/loop54    squashfs   11M   11M       0 100% /snap/auto-cpufreq/129
/dev/loop3     squashfs  360M  360M       0 100% /snap/kdenlive/89
/dev/loop62    squashfs  449M  449M       0 100% /snap/kf5-5-105-qt-5-15-9-core22/11
/dev/loop27    squashfs   91M   91M       0 100% /snap/whatsapp-for-linux/57
/dev/loop43    squashfs   56M   56M       0 100% /snap/core18/2751
/dev/loop63    squashfs  438M  438M       0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-99-qt-5-15-7-core20/7
/dev/loop37    squashfs  6.5M  6.5M       0 100% /snap/curl/1754
/dev/loop18    squashfs   74M   74M       0 100% /snap/core22/750
/dev/loop9     squashfs  143M  143M       0 100% /snap/skype/280
/dev/loop13    squashfs  461M  461M       0 100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/105
/dev/loop28    squashfs  151M  151M       0 100% /snap/chromium/2497
```

Comment: Linux filesystems do not need defragmentation. Only btrfs has the option, but you don't use btrfs.

Comment: Yes it's OK - see [Why are all snaps being mounted and listed as block devices or partitions for Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047456/why-are-all-snaps-being-mounted-and-listed-as-block-devices-or-partitions-for-ub)

Answer (score 0):

`$ lsblk -ape7 -o+LABEL,FSSIZE,FSUSE%` gives you a shorter list of actual disks and partitions with size and used%.

The majority of your list is installed "snap" packages... (including old and disabled)

To somewhat cleanse the snap packages... place this text in a file...

```
B="$(tput rev)"
R="$(tput sgr 0)"
echo -e "\n${B}Snap updates? Current content/list:${R}"
if [ ! -z "$( which snap)" ] ;then
  snap list --all
  echo -e "\n... list of available updates?"
  snap refresh --list | sed -re 's/\x1B.*\[K//'
  echo -e "\nsnap refresh # doing the actual update."
  sudo snap refresh
  echo -e "\nsnap remove # on 'disabled' items..."
  # https://askubuntu.com/a/1040131/289138
  snap list --all | awk '/disabled/{print $1, $3}' |
    while read snapname revision; do
        sudo snap remove "$snapname" --revision="$revision"
    done
else
  echo -e "'snap' not present."
fi
```

... then do `$ source file`

*WARNING: excerpt from my `update` script... untested in this format.*

Comment: Thanks. What's the warning about? Can I run the script or not?

Comment: It should work, but it is "Untested".